# PHP - Long page refresh after post submit

Tags: php

Not sure why this is happening, but after submitting a post, the page refresh is really long. Inspect element shows a 302 found in the Network tab.

```
Remote Address:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80
Request URL:http://example.com/item?id=730
Request Method:POST
Status Code:302 Found

Remote Address:xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80
Request URL:http://example.com/item?id=730
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
```

I use `header("Location: item?id=".$item_id."");` to refresh the page after the form has been submitted.

Comment: Http 302 is the code for a redirect.  This plays well into what you are seeing, since you may be waiting for a long redirect to complete.

Comment: Long redirect. What is that? I recently changed servers. Moved to a cloud hosting 512 RAM. I wasn't experiencing this when the site was hosted on a vps with more RAM and more processing power. Can this be the problem?

Comment: For starters, press `F12` from your Chrome or Firefox browser and then submit the POST. We need to see exactly what is happening during the request.  Right now, we can only speculate.

Comment: Anything can be a problem, actually. Try to debug the code, use oldschool echo in several key places to see which particular line of code causes the wait. This way you can narrow it down by yourself in few minutes.

Comment: When I click submit ... it just stays stuck in Pending for a pretty long time. So it is most likely the code? Not the server?

Comment: Figured it out. I was also sending emails when submitting the form. And on the new server the mail function isn't set up.